# Need to get the value of Employee_name from User model to Employee model

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

**# model 1**

```
class User(models.Model):
    
    JOINING_ROLES_CHOICES= (
        
        ('sde-intern','SDE Intern'),
        ('sde-trainee','SDE Trainee'),
        ('sde_1','SDE I'),
        ('ui/ux','UI/UX Designer'),
        ('quality-engineer-trainee','Quality Engineer Trainee'),
        ('quality-engineer','Quality Engineer'),
        ('product-manager','Product Manager'),
        ('technical-manager','Technical Manager'),
        ('technical-architect','Technical Architect'),
        ('technical-lead','Technical Lead')
        
    )
    BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICES = (
        ('a+','A+'),
        ('a-','A-'),
        ('b+','B+'),
        ('b-','B-'),
        ('ab+','AB+'),
        ('ab-','AB-'),
        ('o+','O+'),
        ('o-','O-')
        
        )

    employee_name = models.CharField(max_length=210)
    dob=models.DateField(max_length=8) 
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None) 
    pancard=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    aadhar=models.CharField(max_length=100,default=None)
    personal_email_id=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    emergency_contact_no=models.IntegerField(default=None)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    relation=models.CharField(max_length=25,default=None)
    blood_group=models.CharField(max_length=25,choices=BLOOD_GROUP_CHOICES,null=True)
    joining_role=models.CharField(max_length=250,choices=JOINING_ROLES_CHOICES,null=True)
    relieving_role=models.CharField(max_length=250,null=True)
    joining_Date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=8,null=True)
    relieving_Date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=20,null=True)
    

def __str__(self):
    return self.firstname
```

**#model 2**

```
class Employeename(models.Model):
    
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    employee = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.employee
```

I need to get the employee_name value from the User model to the Employeename model. Is there any ways to get only employee_name to the employee.

while i tried the above code it it throwing an error as mentioned below:

TypeError at /admin/App/employee/3/change/
**str** returned non-string (type ManyRelatedManager)

Comment: You have two fields named "employee" on the `Employeename` model?

Comment: yes I need the value of 'Employee_name' field as a single field with many to many fields applicable to the 'employee' field output

Comment: you can't have same name in two model objects within same model... change name "employee" in any of the field

Comment: I have tried removing one field and tried but still not getting the value in the database admin, do i need anything in the serializers or views to display the value?

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a `ManyRelatedManager` object with the `__str__` method on the `Employeename`. Convert it to a string:

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee)
```

This is after you remove one of the two model fields with the same name.

On top of that, I see that in your `__str__` method for your `User` model you're returning `self.firstname`, but the model has no attribute `firstname`. This should be throwing an error too. Set it to an existing, required, string-based model field.

Comment: I have removed one employee and given the string function on the method and it is running but I am getting only the object as (object1, object2) but i need the value for that object. (for ex: if i give a name as "vinoth" in "Employee_name" field under "USER" model, iam getting it as "User object1" in my "EmployeeName" model, but i need to get it as "vinoth"). please help on the same

Comment: For your `User` model's `__str__` method return `self.employee_name` and for `Employeename` model return `str(self.employee)`

Comment: I have done it as exactly what you have mentioned but still I am getting the user object only not the value.

Comment: Try returning `self.employee.employee_name` for the `Employeename` model

Comment: I have tired both str(self.employee.employee_name) and self.employee.employee_name in the return type but it throws an error as "AttributeError at /admin/App/employeename/
'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'employee_name'".